# Log in screen before the app

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout

Hey I am working an android app and it's basically just one activity, which is a map, but I want a `Facebook` login screen before they get the layout with the map. Should I make another activity specifically for the log in screen or should I make another layout and use the same activity with two layouts. Also is it generally better to always make another activity for another layouts. Also any other tips around my issue would be appreciated, since a facebook log in screen before your app is pretty common. Thanks!

Comment: You should add splash screen to your application, it should check if user is login or not, and show proper (different) activity for login/create account or your main activity (map)

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing this, check whatever flow works best for you. I'm using a blank activity (without content view) which decides where to go. Depending on some boolean flag the user will go to login or home screen.

Comment: Yeah the blank decider activity is working good for me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For the Facebook Login Screen, here's the link I thought you'd help.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-add-facebook-login-to-your-android-app--cms-23837

About the layouts, in my opinion, in this situation less layouts are better to manipulate but it's still up to you.

Good Luck.

G.